# I have this error : ERROR: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, typescript, import

I need to execute seed file and when I execute the file this error appears. How can I solve it?

> ERROR: Cannot use import statement outside a module

This is my `tsconfig.js`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es2019",
      "lib": [
          "dom",
          "es2019"
      ],
    //   "baseUrl": "./src",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "typeRoots": [
          "./types",
          "./node_modules/@types"
      ],
      
  },  
  "include": [
      "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      ".vscode"
  ]
}
```

And this is my seeds:

```
'use strict';
import { Player } from "../../app/models/player";

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
      return Player.bulkCreate(
        [
          { name: "Inbal", email: "inbal@test.co.il",phone: "1111" },
          { name: "Tal", email: "tal@test.co.il",phone: "2222" },
          { name: "Sivan", email: "sivan@test.co.il" ,phone: "3333"}
        ],
        { hooks: true, individualHooks: true, validate: true }
      );
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.bulkDelete("players", null, {});
  }
};
```

When I run `npx sequelize-cli-ts db:seed:all` the error appears.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `require` instead of import in your seed file or you could also try to set
`"type": "module"`
in your `package.json`